# What are these chess.com figures from my English Opening game?

Tags: analysis, english-opening

I am asking something that chess.com shows about the English Opening, based on a game that I recently played on chess.com

Chess.com showed the following figures:

`1.c4 e5`
.. 
`2.g4 e4 9.6 5.8`

-`White: 9.6`
-`Black: 5.8`

What are these figures? It comes with `Gantt Chart`

As previously mentioned, these numbers are from the chess.com website, specifically from the "15|10" gamemode that I played in.

These figures seem to be common for all chess games. I think that it pertains to Chess Mega Base and Chess Analytics, which was already done, and clearly counted to some number. What is this rational number about.?

Comment: Can you include a small screenshot with the mentioned figures ?

Comment: Sure Isac. Let me add photos regards to this shortly. Busy in a while.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you mean this (correct me if wrong):

[image]

This refers to time in seconds that it took to complete a move. So in this case (my game), it took White 2.5 seconds to make a  move, and 0.9 seconds for Black to respond. Then it took 19.7 seconds for White to make a move, and 1 second for Black to respond.

In your case, it took White 9.6 seconds to make a move, and Black 5.8 seconds to respond.